# How to make a menu (multiple button?) iOs

Tags: ios, swift, menu

I am new in the development of iOS with swift, for the moment everything goes well but there is one thing that I blocked.

How this kind of menu?

[image]

How do you call this ? Because I do not even know what to look for because I do not know his name: /

Sorry for my bad english and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Check here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=popover

Comment: Check here:https://github.com/lminhtm/LMDropdownView

Comment: @Mr.Bond LMDropdownView can be a great idea .. Thanks :)

Comment: You Welcome ..@Insou

Comment: @Insou If you have maintain cell with nsuserdefault then also try this::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215165/how-to-maintain-cell-selection-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

This can be made by using click on button open a view or open a tableview inside the table view put the label on each row and after that use `didselectrowatindexpath` method of tableview for click on each row open the new page or `viewcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table view to show dropdown menu. Show tableview on click and hide when select row. this is the basic concept. and if you not want to code your self then there many third party libraries available on github like [DropDownMenu](https://github.com/diniska/DropDownMenu) or [dropdownment](https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu) etc.

Note : standard way in ios for this kind of stuff(drop down or selection from multiple option) is `UIPickerview`, so you can use this also it very easy. so if not required to use hardcoded dropdown then `pickerview` is best option.

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch your links :)